Trigger a re-render when window.location.search changes
I created a button that changes my route and adds a search param to the URL.
The functionality of the button is as so:
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Link to={`/route/locations?openCertainModal=true`}>
  {placeholder}
</Link>

My problem occurs when I am already in the located in /route/locations. When I click the button and I'm there, the route will change from /route/locations to /route/locations?openCertainModal=true, but since the component is already mounted, no rerender is triggered. How can I trigger a rerender of the component when ?openCertainModal=true is added to the route and window.location.search changes?
I'm using react-router-dom 5.x.x

Adding get parameters is NOT how you navigate in react router. You have rout parameters built into the router, so you need to figure out how to make your application use those instead of ?openCertainModal=true. <Route path="/route/locations/:isOpenCertianModal"> is the way to do it. Adding : at any route location will make that a variable in the URL itself that will be accessible via the useParams hook. useParams().isOpenCertianModal for example

Use the useSearchParams hook in the target component, when the matched route's URL path + searchParams update it should trigger a component rerender.
Basic React-Router-DOM v6 Example:
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, Link, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const RouteLocations = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  ...

  return (
    ...
  );
};

<Route path="/route/locations" element={<RouteLocations />} />


Basic React-Router-DOM v5 Example:
Use the location.search value. It's common to abstract this logic into a custom hook.
import { useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const useSearchParams = () => {
  const { search } = useLocation();

  const searchParams = useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search]);

  return [searchParams];
};

const RouteLocations = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("RouteLocations rendered", searchParams.toString());
  });

  return (
    ...
  );
};

<Route path="/route/locations" component={RouteLocations} />


I didn't know about this hook, thanks. I'm going to look into it, though I'm not sure if it's available on react-router-dom 5.x.x, which is the one that my current project is using.

@GABRIELRGARCIA-AVILES Right, useSearchParams was introduced in RRDv6, but you can use location.search from useLocation in much the same way. I've updated my answer with a RRDv5 example.

Based on Drew's answer, I made this hook to allow getting and setting the URL search params:
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

//A similar function is implemented in react-router-dom v6, but we are using v5 at time of writing
function useSearchParams() {
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();

  const searchParams = useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search]);

  function setSearchParams(key: string, value: string | number | boolean, reload?: boolean) {
    searchParams.set(key, value.toString());

    if (reload) {
      //reloads the page
      window.location.search = searchParams.toString();
    } else {
      history.push(window.location.pathname + "?" + searchParams.toString());
    }
  }

  return { searchParams, setSearchParams };
}

export default useSearchParams;

